# Running Onnx model in F#

Tags: c#, .net, neural-network, f#, onnx

I am currently trying to run a python trained Keras model in .NET. I have converted this model to an Onnx model. I am trying to run this on using ML.NET.

```
input:
  name: input_6
  tensor: float32[unk_297,50]

  name: input_5
  tensor: float32[unk_298,50]

output:
  name: out
  tensor: float32[unk_299,1]
```

I have been following this article from Microsoft translating the code from C# to F#:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automl-onnx-model-dotnet?view=azureml-api-2

Here are the F# types that I created based on my input:

```
#r "nuget: Microsoft.ML"
#r "nuget: Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime, 1.10.0"
#r "nuget: Microsoft.ML.OnnxTransformer"


open Microsoft.ML
open Microsoft.ML.Data
open Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Onnx
open Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.Tensors
open System
open System.IO

[<CLIMutable>]
type OnnxInput = {
    [<ColumnName("input_5");>]
    input1: DenseTensor<float32>
    [<ColumnName("input_6")>]
    input2: DenseTensor<float32>
}


[<CLIMutable>]
type OnnxOutput = {
    [<ColumnName("out")>]
    output: DenseTensor<float32>
}

let onnxModelPath = @""
let mlContext = new MLContext()
let createFloat32DenseTensor (data: float32 array) (dimensions: int array) =
    let memory = Memory<float32>(data)
    let tensor = new DenseTensor<float32>(memory, dimensions)
    tensor
let data = Array.create 50 0f
let dimensions = [| 1; 50 |]

let init = createFloat32DenseTensor data dimensions
let initialOnnxInput = {
    input1 = init
    input2 = init
}
let getPredictionPipeline (mlContext: MLContext) =
    let inputColumns = [|"input_5"; "input_6"|]
    let outputColumns = [|"out"|]
    let onnxPredictionPipeline =
        mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(
                outputColumnNames = outputColumns,
                inputColumnNames = inputColumns,
                modelFile = onnxModelPath
                )
    let emptyDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<OnnxInput>([||])
    onnxPredictionPipeline.Fit(emptyDataView)

let onnxPredictionPipeline = getPredictionPipeline mlContext
let onnxPredictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<OnnxInput, OnnxOutput>(onnxPredictionPipeline)
let testinputName = createFloat32DenseTensor outputResult dimensions

let testInput = {
    input1 = createFloat32DenseTensor outputResult dimensions 
    input2 = createFloat32DenseTensor outputResult dimensions
    }

let prediction = onnxPredictionEngine.Predict testInput
```

When I run:

```
let onnxPredictionPipeline = getPredictionPipeline mlContext
```

I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member input1@ (Parameter 'rawType')
```

How can I create the correct types to correctly run this trained Onnx model?